# webView no carga la página

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

me pasa una cosa muy curiosa y a la cual no encuentro explicación ninguna.

El caso es que en la aplicación, estoy parseando unas noticias y las guardo en `CoreData`, luego muestro el listado de noticias en un `UITableView` y si pulso sobre una de ellas me lleva a un `UIWebView` en la que cargo el enlace con la noticia completa. Ahora viene lo raro...

Si le paso al `NSURL` la variable que contiene la dirección web, No carga. Si le pongo la misma dirección a un `NSString` y le paso ese `NSString` a la `UIWebView`, SÍ carga

```
NSString *berria1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
berria1 = self.abisua.noticia;
NSString *berria2 = @"http://www.vitoria-gasteiz.org/we001/was/we001Action.do?idioma=eu&aplicacion=wb021&tabla=contenido&uid=u_47906a5c_14eabe80aeb__7fe9";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:berria1];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
NSLog(@"El contenido de la noticia 1 es %@", berria1);
NSLog(@"El contenido de la noticia 2 es %@", berria2);
```

Con el NSLog compruebo que los valores de las variables son las mismas como podéis ver en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puede estar pasando?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una duda, si `self.abisua.noticia` ya es un `String` ¿porqué inicializas otro `NSString`? Asignalo directamente...

Comment: Por otro lado, puede ser que al pasar antes por un `NSString` se esté normalizando la URL y entonces sí cargue...

Comment: Hola mhergon, al principio lo pasaba directamente y al ver que no cargaba, he inicializado otro `NSString` para ver si así se solucionaba.

Comment: ¿de qué tipo es `self.abisua.noticia`?

Comment: es de tipo `NSString´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente, he encontrado y solucionado el problema.

El problema era que la variable recibida de `Core Data` y asignada al `NSString` berria1, no se como ni porque, pero tiene añadidos los caracteres "\n    " al final de la `URL`.

El valor de berria1 en al área de debug mostraba lo siguiente:

```
berria1 __NSCFString *  @"http://www.vitoria-gasteiz.org/we001/was/we001Action.do?idioma=eu&aplicacion=wb021&tabla=contenido&uid=u_47906a5c_14eabe80aeb__7fe9\n      "  0x0000000126d9e6c0
```

Entonces, cuando yo pasaba este valor al `NSURL` y este encontraba estos caracteres al final del mismo, ponía el valor de `NSURL` a `nil`.

He solucionado esto, pasando este `NSString` a un `NSMutableString` y eliminando estos caracteres antes de pasar el valor al `NSURL` con el siguiente código:

```
NSString *berria1 = self.abisua.noticia;

NSMutableString * miCadena = [NSMutableString stringWithString: berria1];
[miCadena deleteCharactersInRange: [miCadena rangeOfString: @"\n      "]];
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo.